# Azure Website connecting to Virtual Machine

Tags: azure

I have an Azure Website and it is required to consume an elastic search service that's running on a VM.

Although I need to be able to lock the access to elastic search down so only the Azure Website can access it, I can't seem to work out how to do this using the endpoint configuration on the VM.

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Thanks
Carl

Answer (score 4):

You will need to setup a Hybrid Connection between your Web Site and the VM:

[image]

Hybrid Connections create a safe tunnel between your Web Site and a VM for example. The screenshot shows the integration between a Web Site and the corporate network, but this also works for VMs running in Azure.

The only requirement is that you install the Hybrid Connection Manager on your VM. More information:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/